# Tensorflow not installing: Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... /

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having difficulties installing **Tensorflow** on my *Macbook* in *Visual Studio Code*.
When I run: `pip3 install tensorflow`, it seems like as if it takes forever to install and is stuck in a loop or so.

I am getting the following message: `Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... /`

I have already checked my python version (python 3.10.9) and I have checked my *pip* version (23.3.1), so this shouldn't be a problem.

I dont know what to do.

Comment: Could you add the complete log that you get after duing the `pip3 install tensorflow`

Comment: Hello It seems like I have successfully installed tensorflow, however I cant import it. If I command pip3 show tensorflow: I get: Name: tensorflow
Version: 2.13.0
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/ etc. But If I want to import it I get: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: IF this is another problem create a new quetion with this new problem, necesary information (logs, errors, ...) You can add new questions link here in comments.

Comment: I have a problem importing tensorflow, as I get the following message: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow

Comment: Please, create a new question, this is another problem @EleniSop

Answer (score 0):

Nevertheless, doing the following solved the issue:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install tensorflow
```

This answer is plagiarized from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45445#issuecomment-740482001

Comment: First of all thank you, I installed tensorflow, but I cant import it with: import tensorflow as tf. I always get a false message